# GIT, making changes in the right branch

Tags: git

Suppose you maintain 2 branches, `dev` and `release`.

Other then discipline, how do you force yourself to not make changes in `release` and checkout to `dev`?

**Q1:** If you forgot to do it and made changes in `release`, is there a way to commit them to `dev` instead and abort in `release`?

**Q2:** Are there any common tricks people use to avoid making tons of changes in branch that was not designed for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1**: Yeah, that's pretty simple.  If you've realized you committed to the wrong branch:

```
git checkout dev
git cherry-pick release # you may need to cherry-pick several commits
git checkout release && git reset --hard HEAD^ # or reset to wherever you want
```

**Q2**: I rely heavily on git-completion:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite as sophisticated an answer as you're looking for, but putting your current git branch in your prompt gets you a large part of the way there. You can find lots of recipes out there, but [this one](https://gist.github.com/31631) looks reasonable with a few bells and whistles.

You can also check out [how I do it](https://github.com/craigcitro/craigcitro-dotfiles/blob/master/bashrc#L378).

Comment: Please provide an example of how you do it

Answer (score 1):

I have added a little script to my shell that always shows me what branch I am on. I use [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/) where most themes include this, but there are also some lighter options like the one described [here](http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/git/add-current-git-branch-to-your-bash-prompt).

This way I can tell which branch I am working on and usually don't mess up.

If you already commited to the branch, you can use `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` to rewrite the history and put them on other branches

Comment: How do you find out what branch you are on? Could you please share the script?

Comment: There is a link in the post ... I'll post it again in superverbose: http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/git/add-current-git-branch-to-your-bash-prompt